# Lines() in barplot function not matching with x axis

Tags: r, plot

I made a barplot where x axis are months and y axis is a vector with 12 numbers (in my sample is called a2001 and has different 12 different values).

But then, when I use lines in order to add a line of another vector with another 12 numbers (called "d" in my sample) those 12 numbers ARE NOT matching the 12 months. Does anyone know what is happening?

This is what I got, as you see, the line does not match the months:

[image: result]

This is the code I'm using:

```
b.plot <- barplot(height = a2001, 
                  names.arg = month.abb, 
                  xlab="Date", 
                  ylab="Precipitation (in)",
                  ylim=c(0,12))

lines(d,col="green")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the corresponding `x` arguments for `lines(x, y, ...)` that default to `1:12` at the moment. Actually you already stored them in `b.plot`, so all you need to do is:

```
lines(b.plot, d, col="green")
```